# order by and count in Doctrine Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony1, doctrine

> ```
> id  | name 
> 1   | aaa  
> 2   | bbb  
> 3   | ccc  
> 4   | ccc  
> 5   | aaa  
> 6   | ccc  
> 7   | ccc  
> 8   | aaa  
> 9   | bbb  
> 10  | ccc  
> 11  | aaa
> ```

i would like become:

> ```
> name | count
> ccc  | 5
> aaa  | 4
> bbb  | 2
> ```

orderby count DESC

i made:

> ```
> public function getCount() 
> {        
>         $q = $this->createQuery('q')
>             ->select('*')
>             ->addSelect('count(q.name) as count')
>             ->groupBy('q.name')
>             ->orderBy('count DESC');
>
>         return $q->execute();        
> }
> ```

but if :

> ```
> foreach ($count as $c) {
>   echo $c;
> }
> ```

this show me only first data in table.

how can i make it?

Comment: Just a side note: It is good practice to assign the output of the execute `$result = $q->execute();` and then free the query `$q->free();` and only then return the result `return $result`. This will cause doctrine to free up the query memory for PHP to reuse.

Comment: where i must use $q->free() ?

Comment: directly after the execute. For example: `$result = $q->execute(); $q->free(); return $result;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your loop to this:

```
foreach ($count as $c) {
  echo $c->count . "\n";
}
```

edit:
a good way to debug this is to change your return to

```
$q->fetchArray();
```

and then in your loop

```
print_r($c);
```